# export more than one but not all attributes with qgis2web

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

Using the qgis2web plugin:
Is it possible to select more than one but not all attributes to be shown as popup?
I can select all attributes or only one attribute to be shown. but not for example two attributes.
Neither shift-click nor right-click seem to work. Any workaround (beside deleting all not to be shown attributes and then select all)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid not. It's not supported. It is something I've thought about, but no-one has asked for it until you. I'll look into it, but for now, it's not possible. Apologies.

UPDATE
The best way to achieve this at the moment is to create a new QGIS layer from your existing data, but with only the fields you need. Then export the new layer, not the old one.

UPDATE 2
The other way to achieve this is to edit the layer fields in QGIS and hide the ones you don't want in your Leaflet map by setting their edit widgets to Hidden.

Comment: ok , sorry my mistake: I misinterpreted the text from the help-file:Data export
Delete unused fields 
If not all fields are selected in "Info popup content", remove the undisplayed fields from the GeoJSON - helps to reduce file size

Comment: I'll look at the wording to remove any ambiguity. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've added a feature request for this - no timescales yet: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/205

Comment: I've also reworded that sentence in the README/help. I hope that makes things clear.